# Eloquent, use pluck() to filter a deep collection

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I need to return an array only with the permissions `name` column but cant make it work with a `->pluck()`

```
class User
{
public function roleTeams()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RoleTeam::class);
    }
}
```

```
class RoleTeams
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Role
{
    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
    }
}
```

This is the last code i try based on similar answers i found.

```
$permissions = $user->roleTeams()->with('roles.permissions')->pluck('roles.*.permissions.*.name')->all();
```

The expected result is

```
[
    'edit_user',
    'delete_user',
    ...
]
```

Comment: [Use a HasThroughMany relationship](https://appdividend.com/2018/05/18/laravel-hasmanythrough-relationship-example/)

Comment: This dont make any sense, all the relations are working fine, my problem is return a array only with the permissions.name colum content.

Comment: Use it to get access to a relationship through another relationship. In your case it probably won’t work because you have 3 branched relationships instead of 2. Maybe you should rethink your design.

Comment: Its working perfect with the accepted answer, thanks for your time anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I tried to simulate your situation. My code is:

```
$arr = [
    'id'    => 1,
    'name'  => 'User 1',
    'roles' => [
        [
            'id'          => 2,
            'name'        => 'Admin',
            'permissions' => [
                [
                    'id'   => 8,
                    'name' => 'edit_user',
                    'type' => 'editor',
                ],
                [
                    'id'   => 9,
                    'name' => 'delete_user',
                    'type' => 'deleter',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        [
            'id'          => 3,
            'name'        => 'Manager',
            'permissions' => [
                [
                    'id'   => 6,
                    'name' => 'do_smth1_with_user',
                    'type' => 'smth1',
                ],
                [
                    'id'   => 7,
                    'name' => 'do_smth2_with_user',
                    'type' => 'smth2',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

$collection = collect([$arr]);
```

And have interested results. If use `pluck()` method like in your answer:

```
dd($collection->pluck('roles.*.permissions.*.name'));
```

The result would be like this:

```
Collection {#322 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => array:4 [▼
      0 => "edit_user"
      1 => "delete_user"
      2 => "do_smth1_with_user"
      3 => "do_smth2_with_user"
    ]
  ]
}
```

But if I use `pluck()` with `collapse()` method it looks like you want:

```
dd($collection->pluck('roles')->collapse()->pluck('permissions')->collapse()->pluck('name'));
```

And result is:

```
Collection {#322 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => "edit_user"
    1 => "delete_user"
    2 => "do_smth1_with_user"
    3 => "do_smth2_with_user"
  ]
}
```

To be honest, I don't know why it works like it works, but try to use it with `collapse()` method and let me know if it helps your or not.
Hope my answer helps you to slove your problem.

Comment: Thanks, that works great, but yes, for some reason `-pluck('roles.*.permissions.*.name')` retuns a double array

Comment: Fine. Glad it helped.